# Unexpected output with array of Strings

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, output

I made an array of Strings with following code

```
public class Main 
{
    static String[] words = {"watch", "on", "youtube",":","Mickey","en","de","stomende","drol"};
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String output = "";
        for(int i = 1 ; i <= words.length ; i++)
        {
            output += " " + words[i];
        }

        System.out.println(output);
    }
}
```

What I expected to receive as output was:

> "Watch on youtube : Mickey en de stomende drol"

But the actual output was

> "on youtube : Mickey en de stomende drol"

I think I made a little mistake, how does it come?

Comment: you are starting you for loop with an index value of i = 1 instead of i = 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Errors are as follows:-

1.As you have initialized your words array with argument starting from 0 so you have to start your for loop from 0.

2.There are minor errors in your question as well reagrding declaring words as static and semicolon error which i have edited already in your question.

here is your code working properly:-

```
 public class Main {

 static String[] words =  {"watch", "on", "youtube",":","Mickey","en","de","stomende","drol"};
 public static void main(String[] args){
 String output = "";

 for(int i = 0 ; i <= words.length-1 ; i++)
 {
    output += " " + words[i];
 }

 System.out.println(output);
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 7):

> But the actual output was

[...]

Not with the code you posted. The code you posted wouldn't compile, because:

- You didn't end the field initialization with a semi-colon
- If you had, you'd be trying to access an *instance* field without creating an instance
- After fixing that, you'd have run into an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` for basically the same reason as you missed out the first element - see below.

This:

```
for(int i = 1 ; i <= words.length ; i++)
```

Should be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++)
```

Note that both the start index *and* the loop condition have changed. The latter is the idiomatic way of expressing a loop from 0 (inclusive) to an exclusive upper bound.

Arrays in Java are 0-based - so for example, an array with length 4 has valid indexes of 0, 1, 2 and 3. See the [Java arrays tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) for more details.

(As an aside, repeated string concatenation like this is generally a bad idea. It's not a problem in your case as there are so few values, but you should learn about `StringBuilder`.)

Answer (score 1):

Your index on the loop must start with 0 `for int i=0; .....`, as arrays in java start at position 0 and end at length-1

Answer (score 1):

Your loop should be like this

```
for(int i=0; i<words.length; i++)
```